# Angular2 how to call a method only after subscribed data is completely bounded to a table using ng-for?

Tags: datatable, datatables, angular

I have a table whose data is bounded through a subscription made to an observable. I want to call a method only after the data is completely bounded to the table.

```
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="#resource of resources">
             ....
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the Component Life Cycle provides some events, you can find them here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: The answer in the linked question only works for first render, not when `resources` are added/removed/modified. It also might be called multiple times.